# React Material-UI Select using an array of objects as the source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

Hoping I can get some help. I'm currently following a tutorial that is using React Material-UI, specifically to do with a simple Select drop-down.

They are using the following json dataset object snippet for their code that looks like this:

```
{
  "AF": "Afghanistan",
  "AL": "Albania",
  "DZ": "Algeria",
  "AS": "American Samoa",
  "AD": "Andorra",
  "AO": "Angola",
  "AI": "Anguilla"
}
```

and the React code they use to build the select is as follows, where options here is the above json dataset:

```
  return (
    <TextField>
      {Object.keys(options).map((item, pos) => {
        return (
          <MenuItem key={pos} value={item}>
            {options[item]}
          </MenuItem>
        )
      })}
    </TextField>
  );
```

Now I am trying to build something similar to the above but my dataset is actually an array of objects, i.e.:

```
[
    {
        "job_id": 1,
        "job_name": "Engineer"
    },
    {
        "job_id": 2,
        "job_name": "Scientist"
    },
    {
        "job_id": 3,
        "job_name": "Teacher"
    }
]
```

My question is, how can I achieve the above React code to construct my React Material UI Select but instead of using an object, I would like to use my array of objects where the name shown in the select drop-down is `job_name` and the value return is `job_id`?

I have tried the following, but nothing is returned:

```
{options.map(option => {
          return (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.key}
            </MenuItem>
          )
})}
```

**Added:** In addition to the above, what is the best way of checking between the first dataset (object) and my data set - array of objects and then using this check to distinguish between the two methods of displaying the data within the correct Material-UI Select code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to access the item options differently since key and value are not set in the objects within the array. The possible options are `job_id` and `job_name`.

So try this:

```
{options.map(option => {
          return (
            <MenuItem key={option.job_id} value={option.job_id}>
              {option.job_name}
            </MenuItem>
          )
})}
```

Map will be called on every item so that option here is one of the elements in your array.

Update: to distinguish if the object is an array or not you could use `Array.isArray`:

```
{(Array.isArray(options) ? options.map(({job_id, job_name})=> ([job_id, job_name])) : Object.entries(options)).map(([key,value])=> {
          return (
            <MenuItem key={key} value={key}>
              {value}
            </MenuItem>
          )
})}
```

This would work but maybe should be done separately to keep the jsx lean and avoid overloading the render function.

Comment: I was almost there, just didn't use the correct attributes. I added an additional question about distinguishing b/w object and an array of objects as I would like to check for both types within my code.

Answer (score 2):

**A Complete example with sample component and sample URLs**

```
import { FormControl, InputLabel, MenuItem, Select, SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

type Props = {};

export const ProductsSearch = (props: Props) => {
    var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const requestHeader = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    };

    const [brands, setBrands] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [searchedProducts, setSearchedProducts] = useState<any[]>([]);

    const [brand, setBrand] = useState('');
    const handleChangeBrand = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
        setBrand(event.target.value);
    };

    const [category, setCategory] = useState('');
    const handleChangeCategory = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
        setCategory(event.target.value);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        let brandsUrl = `http://localhost:5000/api/products/brands/all`;
        let categoriesUrl = `http://localhost:5000/api/products/categories/all`;
        let searchedProductsUrl = `http://localhost:5000/api/products/byBrandAndcategory/1/5`;

        axios.all([axios.get(brandsUrl, requestHeader), axios.get(categoriesUrl, requestHeader), axios.get(searchedProductsUrl, requestHeader)]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
            setBrands(responses[0].data);
            setCategories(responses[1].data);
            setSearchedProducts(responses[2].data);
        })).catch(errors => {
            console.log('Error fetching multiple requests');
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <FormControl variant="filled" sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 200 }}>
                <InputLabel id="brand-select-label">Brand</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    labelId="brand-select-label"
                    id="brand-select"
                    value={brand}
                    onChange={handleChangeBrand}
                >
                    {
                        brands.map((brand) => {
                            return <MenuItem value={brand.brand_id} key={brand.brand_id}>{brand.brand_name}</MenuItem>
                        })
                    }
                </Select>
            </FormControl>

            <FormControl variant="filled" sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 200 }}>
                <InputLabel id="category-select-label">Category</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    labelId="category-select-label"
                    id="category-select"
                    value={category}
                    onChange={handleChangeCategory}
                >
                    {
                        categories.map((category) => {
                            return <MenuItem key={category.category_id} value={category.category_id}>{category.category_name}</MenuItem>
                        })
                    }
                </Select>
            </FormControl>

            {brands.length} | {categories.length} | {searchedProducts.length}
        </>
    );
};
```